# understanding the complexity of the code from freecodecamp

Tags: javascript

this question is not meant to find a solution for the task but to understand as the title says.
I could not categorize the question.
Without further ado.
I began practicing Javascript on the website freecodecamp.org last month.
My main concern is the set up of the function:

```js
var someObj = {
  propName: "John"
};

function propPrefix(str) {
  var s = "prop";
  return s + str;
}
var someProp = propPrefix("Name"); // someProp now holds the value 'propName'
console.log(someObj[someProp]); // "John"
```

What I do not understand is the 'function'-part.
What does it return? The return statement returns 's' with its value "prop" and 'str'. But what value does 'str' hold? Is it the whole content of the function propPrefix? Idont seem to be able to  wrap my head around that.

Comment: _“But what value does 'str' hold?”_ - it is a function _parameter_, so it contains whatever gets passed when the function gets called.

Comment: The naming of the function is a bit misleading, It should have been `propSuffix(str)` as the input string is concatenated to the end of existing string `'prop'`

Comment: thanks everyone, i do understand now how parameters of a function are used but i still have one question ( i think this will confuse me since it will require deeper understanding and experience of coding): whats the point of these parameters? why cant i just declare a variable and asign a value to it then declare a function? i mean that would be much simpler to me and isnt simplicity what everyone preaches when it comes down to writing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'Name'` is a paramter and is handed over by the calling of the function.

```js
var someObj = {
    propName: "John"
}; //                +-------+
//                   v       |
function propPrefix(str) {// | 
    var s = "prop"; //       |
    return s + str; //       |
} //                         |
//                           ^
var someProp = propPrefix("Name"); // hand over 'Name' to the function. it became `str`
console.log(someObj[someProp]);
```

Answer (score 1):

function `propPrefix` take a single argument `str`. `propPrefix` always returns `'prop' + str`;

```
function propPrefix(str) { // function propPrefix take a single argument 
  var s = "prop";
  return s + str;
}
```

now we call function `propPrefix` with argument `"name"`, so `str` takes value of `"Name"`

```
var someProp = propPrefix("Name");
```

this function call can be visualized as

```
function propPrefix("Name") { // function propPrefix take a single argument 
  var s = "prop";
  return s + "Name"; // that will "propName"
}
```

another example

```
var someProp = propPrefix("AnotherProperty");
```

means that `str` now take value of `"AnotherProperty"`, so you can imagine the function like this

```
function propPrefix("AnotherProperty") { // function propPrefix take a single argument 
  var s = "prop";
  return s + "AnotherProperty"; // that will "propAnotherProperty"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass some values (referred as parameters) to your functions. In this case
`function propPrefix(str)`
has a perimeter named str. At the time of calling this function you will have a value (referred as argument) to this function. In this case
`propPrefix("Name")` you are sending `"Name"` as an argument. You can read more about JavaScript functions from [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
var someObj = {
  propName: "John"
};
function propPrefix(str) {
  var s = "prop";
  return s + str;
}
var someProp = propPrefix("Name"); // someProp now holds the value 'propName'
console.log(someObj[someProp]); // "John"
```

- `var someProp = propPrefix("Name");` // we are initializing someProp to value returned from functioncall - propPrefix("Name")
- `propPrefix("Name")` // here we are making function call with parameter "Name" so it will be passed
- `function propPrefix(str) {` //here function is receiving the parameter value "Name" and its assigned to str i.e str value will be "Name"
- `var s = "prop";` // here we are initializing the variable s to "prop"
- `return s + str;//`here we are concatinating s variable with str variable so s's value is "prop" and str value is "Name" concatination gives "propName" and its returning this value;
- `var someProp = propPrefix("Name");`// propPrefix returned "propName" so it will be assigned to   someProp variable so someProp value is "propName"
- We can access the value of a property using [ ] notation 
  `object["propertynamehere"]` // no need for quotes
- `let obj={propName:"Bro";}`
- `someObj[propName]` will return "Bro"
- `console.log(someObj[someProp]);` `equivalent to console.log("bro");`